# Magento 2: How to override the magnifier.js?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, overrides, theme-fallback

I had a requirement that the entire image need not be zoomable, and I had to scale the image to take the full width on the product page so I modified the magnifier.js according to my requirement. Now I modified it in the lib folder directly, which is not a good way.

How can I override or use a custom magnifier library with my theme?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file to your theme like that path below to override the default.

```
/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/lib/web/magnifier/magnifier.js
```

Answer (score 2):

The right path to override magnifier.js - `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/magnifier/magnifier.js`